# How to achieve custom sort in primeng

Tags: angular, sorting, primeng, primeng-table

I am having a data like below in the p-table column

SUN - 1,
SUN - 2,
...
SUN - 11,
SUN - 12,

While doing sort it is behaving abnormal. It is not sorting based on number after dash. How to achieve sorting with this format.

I tried to add custom sort

.html
`<p-table sortFunction)="customSort($event)" [customSort]="true"></p-table>`

.ts

```
    customSort(event: SortEvent) {
       event.data.sort((data1, data2) => {

        let value1 = data1[event.field];

        let value2 = data2[event.field];

        let result = null;

        if (value1 == null && value2 != null)
            result = -1;
        else if (value1 != null && value2 == null)
            result = 1;
        else if (value1 == null && value2 == null)
            result = 0;
        else if (typeof value1 === 'string' && typeof value2 === 'string')
            result = value1.localeCompare(value2);
        else
            result = (value1 < value2) ? -1 : (value1 > value2) ? 1 : 0;

        return (event.order * result);
    });
   }
```

Here I link stacblitz code for similar issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablesort-demo-rfn6zn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproductservice.ts,src%2Fassets%2Fproducts-small.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the number value, then do the compare when the values contain `SUN`. Please check the below code.

```
  sortTableData(event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.data.sort((data1, data2) => {
      let value1 = data1[event.field];
      let value2 = data2[event.field];
      let result = null;
      if (value1 == null && value2 != null) {
        result = -1;
      } else if (value1 != null && value2 == null) {
        result = 1;
      } else if (value1 == null && value2 == null) {
        result = 0;
      } else if (typeof value1 === 'string' && typeof value2 === 'string') {
        if (value1.includes('SUN') && value2.includes('SUN')) {
          const leftSplit = value1.split(' - ');
          const rightSplit = value2.split(' - ');
          const left = leftSplit.length ? +leftSplit[1] : 0,
            right = rightSplit.length ? +rightSplit[1] : 0;
          result = left < right ? -1 : left > right ? 1 : 0;
        } else {
          result = value1.localeCompare(value2);
        }
      } else {
        result = value1.localeCompare(value2);
      }
      return event.order * result;
    });
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablesort-demo-kumap7)

Comment: It is working fine for all strings contains SUN. But the basic sorting is not working. In asc sorting the text starting with C,G comes after SUN.First we have to sort the first word in either asc or desc order then the number after that the code

Comment: @DianaBetcy updated my answer!

Comment: I too found the solution. Thank you so much for your response

Comment: @DianaBetcy You're welcome!